# How to display an Alert if the user didn't update the Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am launch an major update to my Application and was wondering If I could detect if the user doesn't update the Application to send an alert to the user, like in Chrome it displays an alert if you don't update the Application.

The Image:
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Chrome looks for a new released version on server and then displays the message. To inform your application about the update, try sending PUSH notifications to your application. Handle the information from the PUSH notification such that you can use it to check if the application is updated or not. Probably you can add a version number to your Message body.
Once you have a new version ready on App Store, send a PUSH notification to the devices registered for your app and that should tell the user that an update is available. Subsequently, you can use timer to check if the app is updated to latest version.

However, the primary requirement here is to have a web-server to store the APNS tokens of the devices interested in getting updates.

Comment: A tutorial would be awesome

Comment: Here you go: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: Thanks Push Notification is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTimer method after detection and give particular time to it and throw a method in

which you give alert view & message to alert. and when user update stop NSTimer.

Comment: Nice but how can I detect if the user hasn't installed the update :)

Comment: You can also do one thing more. give a button of update in main screen of your App and on that button tape give alert that you want to update or not. on yes press give what you want.In this way it is not your headache of updation...

Comment: For first answer implement UIGestureRecognizer method on update button that detect touch on button and when you get touch of button then do as I am said in answer...